# VS 2017 ASP.Net Core Web Application cannot target .Net Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I seem to have lost the ability to create an ASP.Net Core Web Application that targets the .Net Framework. The dropdown is disabled where it used to be enabled.

[image]

I have .Net 471, 472 SDKs and targeting packs installed and my VS2017 is updated to 15.7.6.

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling the .Net 4.7x SDKs and targeting packs but that didn't help.

Is there something short of reinstalling Visual Studio from scratch that I can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project template only supports .NET Core. However, once you create the project, you can edit your `.csproj` and change:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
```

To:

```
<TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
```

Save, and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks. I was just about to fix that. Forgot the `4` because I'm not caffienated enough yet.

Comment: caffeinated enough to answer it faster than me... [shakes fist] :-).

Comment: Is this a recent change? I was able to change that dropdown up until this update. I was aware that you could edit the csproj file directly but I was concerned about the integrity of my install.

Comment: The ASP.NET Core team goes back and forth on it. They've removed and added back full framework support multiple times. I think the idea is that they're trying to nudge you away from that path by not presenting it as an option in the GUI. Frankly, there's very little reason at this point to actually use the full framework unless you're dealing with lots of Windows-specific APIs. With .NET Standard 2.0, you can utilize virtually any full framework library in your project targeting .NET Core 2.0+.

Comment: Well, it would have been nice to have some documentation to that fact. I can't find anything regarding removing that ability. We're developing in-house apps for Microsoft Windows based servers and targeting the .Net FW is a safe bet for us. But if this is way of things...so be it.

Comment: That's actually the wrong approach. You should target .NET Core until you cannot, not start with .NET Framework. It's not just about being cross-platform; running on .NET Core takes out a ton of headaches associated with using and maintaining the full framework.

Comment: I agree. However when you're trying to convince a large corporate IT developer community to move to Core, telling them they can still target .Net framework was a carrot....

Comment: I guess it's besides the point now, but *The project template only supports .NET Core.* doesn't seem to be correct - I'm using the same VS version and have the option for choosing .NET Framework that's missing in the screenshot here.

Comment: Interesting. My is the same as the OP's. Also 15.7.6. Also with all the full framework SDK and targeting packs installed. What version of .NET Core are you running?

Comment: I resinstalled the SDK 2.1.301 and now under the Web templates I have the ASP.Net Core Web Application template which then allows me to change the targeted framework. Wow talk about confusing..

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that there are two templates now that can create an ASP.Net Core Web Application.

Under .Net Core

[image]

And under Web

[image]

To get the option of selecting to target .Net Core or .Net Framework, you must use the template under Web.

[image]